# Rainbow trout fishing on a small, deep lake in eastern Ontario

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle, lakes, bait, trout-fishing

I want to fish for rainbow trout in a lake called [Mair Lake](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/45%C2%B006%2730.3%22N+76%C2%B049%2749.2%22W/@45.1098119,-76.8339235,1568m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m4!3m3!8m2!3d45.1084167!4d-76.8303333?entry=ttu) on Crown land in eastern Ontario:

[image]

Map source: [Fish ON-Line](https://www.lioapplications.lrc.gov.on.ca/fishonline/Index.html?viewer=FishONLine.FishONLine&locale=en-CA)

---

**Details:**

1. Lake width: 1 km wide (0.6 miles)
2. Max depth: 53 metres (175 ft).
   Here's a  [bathymetry map](https://fishing-app.gpsnauticalcharts.com/i-boating-fishing-web-app/fishing-marine-charts-navigation.html?title=Mair%20Lake%20boating%20app#16.19/45.10882/-76.83004) (units: feet):

   [image]
3. Geography: The shoreline appears to be a mixture of shallow areas (possibly sandy) and very deep areas (presumably rocky) (units: metres):
   [image]
   [Google Image search](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=564422861&q=%22mair%20lake%22%20frontenac&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiln_6xlqOBAxWjkIkEHZgPDIcQ0pQJegQICxAB) has some photos of the shoreline too.
4. Timing: I haven't been to this lake yet, as it is fairly remote. But I plan to be in the area soon (mid-September, 2023).
5. Access: I can use a boat or a canoe. There are campsites along the shore for shore fishing, too.
6. Stocking: According to Fish ON-Line, the lake has been **stocked with rainbow trout** from 2013 to the present (2023):

   [image]
7. For what it's worth, I found a [picture](https://www.anglersatlas.com/media/photos/5a5cfef3c42df.jpg) on [anglersatlas.com](https://www.anglersatlas.com/place/125241/mair-lake) (and a [bathymetry map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MBLC.jpg)) from someone who caught a large rainbow trout on Mair Lake in December 2018. I've tried contacting that person.

---

**Question:**

What techniques should I use when fishing for rainbow trout in such a lake? I've done lots of basic fishing with a worm/bobber/hook. But not much else; I haven't fished for trout.

For example, do rainbow trout go deep at this time of year in this climate? Should I use a spoon lure or live bait?

Answer (score 3):

Beautiful area and picturesque lake for boat-in camping. But good luck trying to catch a Rainbow Trout. Three of us camped there for 3 full days a week ago (14,15,16 Sept 2023) and didn't get even a bite. We initially trolled with lures and then resorted to live bait minnows and worms (we'd brought along a minnow trap and a shovel) but still came up empty handed. Others in boats out on the lake weren't getting any bites either. I suspect increased traffic as a consequence of the pandemic stay-at-home directives brought out many more fishermen over the past few years than there are stocked trout in the lake!  There are perch and sunfish there though if wetting a line is all you're seeking to do.

Comment: Are you one of the guys I talked to on the morning of Thurs, Sept 14th? I had a white truck, an aluminum boat/trailer (but I didn't use it), and a red canoe. I didn't catch anything either, but I only tried for half a day.